# Why do I need to write alert() after calling google map api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want to add markers on the google map when I get ajax markers data and call  `initMap` function after that map doesn't load but when I add an alert before  `initMap` function, map is loaded.

this works and shows the map and markers:

```
$('#ddlLatLog').on("change", function() {
  jQuery.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetLatLog", "MyTheme", new { area = "" })', {
      id: $(this).find('option:selected').attr('Value')
    },
    function(jdata) {
      markermap = jdata;
    });
  alert(markermap);
  initMap(centermap, markermap);
});
```

don't load map

```
$('#ddlLatLog').on("change", function() {
   jQuery.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetLatLog", "MyTheme", new { area = "" })', {
       id: $(this).find('option:selected').attr('Value')
     },
     function(jdata) {
       markermap = jdata;
     });
   // alert(markermap);
   initMap(centermap, markermap);
 });
```

call google api:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.26&key=...callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

why do I need the alert?

Comment: This no doubt doesn't function at all because you have a missing single quote in your selector.`$('#ddlLatLog).on` should be `$('#ddlLatLog').on`

Comment: ops i forget when copy code tanQ but in my project have '' :D tanQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for map not loading without `alert` is that `jQuery.getJSON` is an `async` call. So when you put `alert`, browser gets time to complete the `ajax` call and response comes back before `initMap` gets invoked. But in other case its not happening as you remove the `alert`. To overcome this; you just need to move your `initMap(centermap, markermap);` within success handler of `jQuery.getJSON` as follows:

```
$('#ddlLatLog').on("change", function() {
  jQuery.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetLatLog", "MyTheme", new { area = "" })', {
      id: $(this).find('option:selected').attr('Value')
    },
    function(jdata) {
      markermap = jdata;

      initMap(centermap, markermap);
    });
});
```

Comment: Also missing single quote in the selector `$('#ddlLatLog).on` should be `$('#ddlLatLog').on`

Comment: Oh...good catch. I just copy pasted the OP's code without seeing that line..thanks @NewToJS.